# Highcharts bar chart rendering issue - bars getting rendered under each other

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm seeing a strange issue with a Highcharts bar chart.  I am trying to render just under 10k items, and I have my plot options series `turboThreshold` set to 50k.

The issue is happening whether I structure my series as an array of objects

```
series: [
    {
        name: "string",
        y: number
    }
]
```

or as an array of arrays

```
series: [
    [
        "string",
        number
    ]
]
```

What's happening is that, up to 4004 items, the chart renders fine.  With 4005 items, the top bar is moved down one and is rendered under the second bar.  With 4006, the top two are rendered under the third, etc.  The x-axis labels remain fine, it's just the bars themselves that move.

Here is a screen shot with 4007 (4004 + 3) items.  As you can see, the top three bars are under the fourth.

[image: badly rendered bar chart]

With the full 10k items, you have to scroll most of the way down (~6000 bars) to see the "first" bar.

I have a calculation to determine the height of the chart based on the number of items, to keep the bar size roughly the same, and that seems to be working fine.  Inspecting the containing `div` shows that it is indeed the height set by the calculation, and the chart renders all of the x-axis labels correctly (even if I let through the full 10k items, the last one is right there at the bottom of the chart).

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?  At 4004 items the chart height is 100100 px, is there some kind of limit or threshold within SVG that might be causing the issue?

(Highcharts 4.1.9, jQuery 1.11.3 for backwards compatability.)

---

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpre19ko/3/) showing the behavior.  Apparently it is related to the fact that I have my y-axis opposite (so the scale is on top) and the y-axis and chart titles set to `display: none`.

Still would appreciate any ideas on how to deal with this.  I would rather not have to show a y-axis title or chart title, but even if I do show them, the behavior still happens.

---

I agree with what @Mark said in the comments, it seems to be a bug in Highcharts, but it does not have to do with the visibility of the chart title or y-axis title.  I did a little more playing around in [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpre19ko/4/), and found that the problem is related to the chart height.  A chart height of `100050px` renders fine, no matter how many items are in it.  At `100075px` the top bar looks slightly off, and at `100100px` it is definitely wrong.

The reason the problem was occurring for me at around 4000 items is that I was setting the chart height like this:

```
$('#container').height(function(){
    return Math.max(400, (25 * numItems));
});
```

`4002 * 25 = 100050` and `4003 * 25 = 100075`, which is why it seemed to start right around that threshold.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  [I attempted to but am having no luck](http://jsfiddle.net/87ya24p5/).

Comment: Please try to set a [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointRange)

Comment: @Mark, see link in updated question.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, setting an explicit point range does not seem to solve it, see link to fiddle in updated question.

Comment: @DylanCristy, looks like a bug in Highcharts.  It's caused by the `display: none` styles on the yAxis and chart titles.  My guess would be that Highcharts starts its position calculations with the heights of those elements intact.  You could use `style: {
      "visibility": "hidden"
    }` but you'd be left with "blank" spaces.

Comment: @Mark actually it seems like it has nothing to do with the visibility of the titles, same problem happens if they are `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.  Seems like it has to do with the overall chart height.  See my link to an updated fiddle.